# Pyqt and general python, can this be considered a correct approach for coding?

Tags: python, design-patterns, pyqt

I have a dialog window containing check-boxes, when each of them is checked a particular class needs to be instantiated and a run a a task on a separated thread (one for each check box). I have 14 check-boxes to check the `.isChecked()` property and is comprehensible checking the returned Boolean for each of them is not efficient and requires a lot more coding.

Hence I decided to get all the children items corresponding to check-box element, get just those that are checked, appending their names to list and loop through them matching their name to d dictionary which key is the name of the check box and the value is the corresponding class to instantiate.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
# class dictionary 

    self.summary_runnables = {'dupStreetCheckBox': [DupStreetDesc(),0],
                              'notStreetEsuCheckBox': [StreetsNoEsuDesc(),1],
                              'notType3CheckBox': [Type3Desc(False),2],
                              'incFootPathCheckBox': [Type3Desc(True),2],
                              'dupEsuRefCheckBox': [DupEsuRef(True),3],
                              'notEsuStreetCheckBox': [NoLinkEsuStreets(),4],
                              'invCrossRefCheckBox': [InvalidCrossReferences()],
                              'startEndCheckBox': [CheckStartEnd(tol=10),8],
                              'tinyEsuCheckBox': [CheckTinyEsus("esu",1)],
                              'notMaintReinsCheckBox': [CheckMaintReins()],
                              'asdStartEndCheckBox': [CheckAsdCoords()],
                              'notMaintPolysCheckBox': [MaintNoPoly(),16],
                              'notPolysMaintCheckBox': [PolyNoMaint()],
                              'tinyPolysCheckBox': [CheckTinyEsus("rd_poly",1)]}


# looping through list
    self.long_task = QThreadPool(None).globalInstance()
    self.long_task.setMaxThreadCount(1)
    start_report = StartReport(val_file_path)
    end_report = EndReport()
    # start_report.setAutoDelete(False)
    # end_report.setAutoDelete(False)
    end_report.signals.result.connect(self.log_progress)
    end_report.signals.finished.connect(self.show_finished)
    # end_report.setAutoDelete(False)
    start_report.signals.result.connect(self.log_progress)
    self.long_task.start(start_report)
    # print str(self.check_boxes_names)
    for check_box_name in self.check_boxes_names:
        run_class = self.summary_runnables[check_box_name]
        if run_class[0].__class__.__name__ is 'CheckStartEnd':
            run_class[0].tolerance = tolerance
        runnable = run_class[0]()
        runnable.signals.result.connect(self.log_progress)
        self.long_task.start(runnable)
    self.long_task.start(end_report)
```

**example of a runnable (even if some of them use different global functions)**

I  can't post the global functions that write content to file as they are too many and not all 14 tasks execute the same type  function. arguments of these functions are int keys to other dictionaries that contain the report static content and the SQL queries to return report main dynamic contents.

```
class StartReport(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        super(StartReport,self).__init__()
        # open the db connection in thread
        db.open()
        self.signals = GeneralSignals()
        # self.simple_signal = SimpleSignal()
        # print self.signals.result
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.task = "Starting Report"
        self.progress = 1
        self.org_name = org_name
        self.user = user
        self.report_title = "Validation Report"
        print "instantiation of start report "

    def run(self):
        self.signals.result.emit(self.task, self.progress)
        if self.file_path is None:
            print "I started and found file none "
            return
        else:
            global report_file
            # create the file and prints the header
            report_file = open(self.file_path, 'wb')
            report_file.write(str(self.report_title) + ' for {0} \n'.format(self.org_name))
            report_file.write('Created on : {0} at {1} By : {2} \n'.format(datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
                                                                                datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),
                                                                                str(self.user)))
            report_file.write(
                "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ \n \n \n \n")
            report_file.flush()
            os.fsync(report_file.fileno())


class EndReport(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super(EndReport,self).__init__()
        self.signals = GeneralSignals()
        self.task = "Finishing report"
        self.progress = 100


    def run(self):
        self.signals.result.emit(self.task, self.progress)
        if report_file is not None:
            # write footer and close file
            report_file.write("\n \n \n")
            report_file.write("---------- End of Report -----------")
            report_file.flush()
            os.fsync(report_file.fileno())
            report_file.close()
            self.signals.finished.emit()
            # TODO: checking whether opening a db connection in thread might affect the db on the GUI
            # if db.isOpen():
            #     db.close()
        else:
            return


class DupStreetDesc(QRunnable):
    """
    duplicate street description report section creation
    :return: void if the report is to text
            list[string] if the report is to screen
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super(DupStreetDesc,self).__init__()
        self.signals = GeneralSignals()
        self.task = "Checking duplicate street descriptions..."
        self.progress = 16.6

    def run(self):
        self.signals.result.emit(self.task,self.progress)
        if report_file is None:
            print "report file is none "
            # items_list = write_content(0, 0, 0, 0)
            # for item in items_list:
                 # self.signals.list.emit(item)
        else:
            write_content(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Now, I used this approach before and it has always worked fine without using multiprocessing. In this case it works good to some extent, I can run the tasks the first time but if I try to run for the second time I get the following Python Error :

```
self.long_task.start(run_class[0])
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type DupStreetDesc has been deleted
```

I tried to use `run_class[0].setAutoDelete(False)` before running them in the loop but pyQt crashes with a minidump error (I am running the code in QGIS) and I the programs exists with few chances to understand what has happened.

On the other hand, if I run my classes separately, checking with an if else statement each check-box, then it works fine, I can run the tasks again and the C++ classes are not deleted, but it isn't a nice coding approach, at least from my very little experience.

Is there anyone else out there who can advise a different approach in order to make this run smoothly without using too many lines of code? Or knows whether there is a more efficient pattern to handle this problem, which I think must be quite common?

Comment: Seems that you lose your object references somehow. Try if putting `self.summary_runnables = {key: value for key, value in self.summary_runnables.items()}` at the end of your  loop helps?

Comment: Could you show me where you would put that piece of code using my code and using the variable names I use, please?

Comment: Put   `self.summary_runnables = {key: value for key, value in self.summary_runnables.items()} ` just after  `self.long_task.start(run_class[0])` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you should create a new instance of each runnable, and allow Qt to automatically delete it. So your dictionary entries could look like this:

```
    'dupStreetCheckBox': [lambda: DupStreetDesc(), 0],
```

and then you can do:

```
for check_box_name in self.check_boxes_names:
    run_class = self.summary_runnables[check_box_name]
    runnable = run_class[0]()
    runnable.signals.result.connect(self.log_progress)
    self.long_task.start(runnable)
```

I don't know why `setAutoDelete` does not work (assuming you are calling it *before* starting the threadpool). I suppose there might be a bug, but it's impossible to be sure without having a fully-working example to test.

Comment: The suggested solution works, but as you said there certainly is a bug in the code, not easy to find in 14 different threads though (for me). When I set autodelete to False the code crashes at the end. It executes all the threads correctly and then crashes. The Threadpool runs threads that call other global functions in the module where the threads are, passing parameters and writing to a file as result. I will post the code as  follows, if you want have a look and let me know if you spot something not completely correct.

Comment: @user3523583. If you use `setAutoDelete(False)`, you must keep a reference (because Qt doesn't take ownership of the objects) - but it appears you are not doing that for `start_report` and `end_report`.

Comment: I commented the lines because it made my code crash but if you pretend that those lines are not commented, there is where I tried to set the autodelete properties, right after the instatiation of the start and end report runnable classes . Can I ask, what does exactly "keep a reference" mean? Thanks for helping

Comment: @user3523583. I'm assuming that the first section of code in your question is part of a method, and so `start_report` and `end_report` will be garbage-collected when they go out of scope (i.e. when the method returns). So you'd need something like `self.end_report = EndReport()` to stop that happening (or you could keep them in the dictionary along with all the other runnables).

Comment: If I set autodelete= False the code crashes, if I leave the code alone recreating the classes every time it doesn't. Start and End are the only classes that are not part of the loop and if I don't set autodelete = false (which means that they should be delete after they execution) they are recreated each time the code runs (right after  setMaxThreadCount(1)). I still do not get why autodelete=False makes everything break. Your solution worked but I would have preferred get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @user3523583. If autodelete is true, Qt will take ownership of the objects, and you don't need to keep an explict reference in Python. But if autodelete is false, Qt will **not** take ownership, so you **must** keep an explicit reference on the Python side. If you don't, the Python garbage-collector will delete them when they go out of scope.